# Rails handling 404's differently for different request types

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have an API in the same app (but different controllers and namespaces) as standard views and controllers to handle the same resources.

At present when I get a 404, regardless of whether the request was made as HTML or json, I receive an HTML 404 response.

Application controller section to handle 404 as follows:

```
unless Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local
      rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :render_denied_404
      rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, with: :render_404
      rescue_from ::AbstractController::ActionNotFound, with: :render_404
      rescue_from ActionController::UnknownController, with: :render_404
      rescue_from ActionView::MissingTemplate, with: :render_404
end

def render_404(e = Exception.new)
      Rails.logger.info "Rendering 404: #{e.to_s}"
      flash[:error] = "Error 404 " + e.to_s
      redirect_to "/404"
end
```

How can I change this to deal with the 404 error differently depending on the request format type?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `respond_to` and `respond_with` blocks to respond differently depending on how you want to respond.

[API documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_with)

[Blog Article](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2009/08/embracing-rest-with-mind-body-and-soul/)

[Rails Cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/224-controllers-in-rails-3)